# Google Street View with Image Only

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to open a location in Google Street View and have it show ONLY the Street View image?

For example, if I open the following link:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&output=svembed&layer=c&cbll=34.9032895146312,-82.3337301891165&cbp=0,0,0,0,0

I want to set the attributes so that the navigation tools, the full screen button, and the overview map button are all gone from the screen.  If possible, I would also like to be able to remove the Google logo at the bottom left.

Can this be done?

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: You cannot remove the Google Logo - it breaks the terms of use.

Comment: That's fine, removing the navigation tools is more important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Static Version](https://web.archive.org/web/20100818173558/http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2010/05/15/google-streetview-static-api/).

[Live Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20140704232630/http://geo.jamiethompson.co.uk/streetview_tiles.php?postcode=SW1W%209TQ&zoom=3).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick tutorial of the Google Street View Image API, which returns the user with an image from the Google Street View. Check out http://goo.gl/t0Pyc